# Added a command-line target to my Swift app, but it does not see the rest of the project

Tags: swift, xcode

I originally created my project using Xcode's templates for iOS, and then arranged my files into "core" logic and "iOS" GUI. core contains a single file, Game.swift.

Now I've added a CLI target as well. However, the CLI target doesn't seem to "see" the files in core, and when I try to init the main object, I get:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'Game'
```

I assume this is because adding a target after-the-fact failed to set up a Search Path or similar in the target, but I'm looking around and don't see anything obvious.

Comment: Have you added your “core” files to the new target?

Comment: No, I guess that's what I'm asking. This appeared to be done automatically in the iOS target so I never had to do this manually before.

Comment: You do that in the Inspectors area (the rightmost one). Select one or more files in the Project Navigator and look for the part labeled Target membership

Comment: Oh geez, thank you!